# Am I using a cron job correctly with this DB design?

Tags: database, cron

I would like to allow users to track GPU prices and email them when they hit a price point.

I need to store:

User data (id/email/info/email)

Video cards (itemID/price)

Users Tracking Video Cards (userID/Video Card/PriceAlertAtThisPRice)

Then run 2 cron jobs. 1 to update the video cards price table constantly (and also remove items from the tracked GPU list when no user is tracking it) 
and 1 to go through each user's tracked items and send an email when a price alert is required (maybe every 5 minutes)

Is this correct or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. The tracking table should use video card ID.
2. Have only 1 cron job to update all prices every X minutes.
3. At the end of this job, check the prices for each GPU and compare to all the targets. Only send 1 email to each subscriber for all the subscriptions he has whose targets are met. Then unsubscribe that user from each subscribed GPU+target combination (delete the row).

Edit: to elaborate on the last part.
You probably have more users than GPUs.

- Select each GPU, currentPrice from the GPU table.
- Select each user from the UsersTrackingGPUs table where the target is >= GPU.currentPrice.
- Keep track of what you're selecting so that you only send 1 email for each user regardless of how many tracked GPUs he matched. Something like:

  discovered = { user1: [GPU1: $50, GPU2: $200], ... }

For each user in discovered:
Send 1 email with all matched GPUs.

For each matched user+GPU combination in discovered:
- Delete the row from UsersTrackingGPUs.

Apologies for the poor formatting, I'm not very proficient with this on mobile..

Edit again: more details.

Something like this: select * from UsersTrackingGPUs utg join GPU g on gtu.id=g.id group by utg.user_id having g.price <= utg.tracking_price

Sorry, I'm not going to get access to a PC for some time, but I think that should be close to what you need -- all users with all GPUs that they are tracking such that their track price is above the current price.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: the worst case for the API (max requests/max gpus ish) should take like 10-15 seconds as to not get throttled to populate a 'full' table of GPU's, so I think that's fine. How do I handle doing the later part of the job per user? Select each user, then query the UsersTrackingGPU table once per user as I iterate through the user list?

Comment: So, update table. Then select * from table, hold results in a dict in memory. Select * from users, then iterate through this list selecting the GPUS they track, then check and email if needed? So 1 query/user?

Comment: 1 query / GPU is cheaper since you probably have more users than GPUs. Check my edit.

Comment: Is there a better way to execute this? If I query per GPU, I'll get back multiple result sets with users repeated and have to filter that in code. Is that ideal? And thanks btw :)

Comment: Check my edit, I think that's what you need (or close enough!)